# Installutil completed successfully but service is not showing up on services

Tags: .net, windows-services

I installed the service manually using installutil option. but it is not showing in the services list. The command i ran was below and i ran it as an administrator.

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
installutil.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\CRM\CRM Server Components\Workflow Service-TEST2\CRM.Studio.WorkflowService.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use SC command.

The SC command communicates with the Windows Service Controller and installed services. When used with its create command option, you can use it to create a Windows service.

Read [1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289.aspx) & [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251192) for more information

```
sc [<ServerName>] create [<ServiceName>] [type= {own | share | kernel | filesys | rec | interact type= {own | share}}] [start= {boot | system | auto | demand | disabled}] [error= {normal | severe | critical | ignore}] [binpath= <BinaryPathName>] [group= <LoadOrderGroup>] [tag= {yes | no}] [depend= <dependencies>] [obj= {<AccountName> | <ObjectName>}] [displayname= <DisplayName>] [password= <Password>]
```

For your question, it should be similar to following

```
sc create "CRM.Studio.WorkflowService.exe" binpath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\CRM\CRM Server Components\Workflow Service-TEST2\CRM.Studio.WorkflowService.exe" displayname= "CRM.Studio.WorkflowService.exe"
```

**NOTE:** Please be mindful of spaces between '=' sign while using SC command.

Answer (score 0):

check your command again as below. You actually uninstalled the assembly and not installed. Specifying `-u` uninstalls the assembly.

```
installutil.exe -u "C:\Program Files...
```

Quoted from documentation:

> If the /u or /uninstall switch is specified, it uninstalls the
>   assemblies, otherwise it installs them.

You shouldn't specify the `-u` option and your command should just be

```
installutil.exe "C:\Program Files....."
```

To know more, in Visual Studio command prompt type `installutil.exe /?` which will show you the available options.

Comment: cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
installutil.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\CRM\CRM Server Components\Workflow Service-TEST2\CRM.Studio.WorkflowService.exe"

Comment: So what happens, does it say success/ enable logging and see if you see any error.

Comment: it is success and no errors in the installutil log file. but it is still not showing. Any other way of finding error which cause

Comment: I do not have the code as I'm not a developer. it is already built in the program i just asked to run the above exe (CRM.Studio.WorkflowService.exe) using intstallutil command in command prompt.

Comment: That may not be the actual registered service name. See what's the service name in code and search for that in `services.msc`. Else, I am out of idea.

Comment: That is a actual service name. I have been installing this for other clients where it worked without any issues. it only did not work one of the particular client. quite annoying. Thanks for the help so far.